# IE10 hiding images after jQuery/css animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, internet-explorer-10

Hi guys I am having an issue with my company's website. The problem only exists in IE10 and I can't seem to figure out why.

I am using the jQuery.appear plugin along with animate.css in order to "BounceIn" some images when the user scrolls to a certain part of a page. The confusing part is that the effect works on other pages.

In IE10 the images animate in and then become completely transparent an disappear instead of starting out transparent, animating in and then become opaque like they do in every other browser.

If you all could give me some assistance I would really appreciate it. I have linked to one of the pages with the problem below.

http://www.storageinternetmarketing.com/self-storage-seo

the javascript code is located here:

http://www.storageinternetmarketing.com/_/js/functions.js

and begins on line 106

The images of concern are the search engine logos directly below the first paragraph of text.

Comment: The link to your source code is bad.

Comment: Really? It is working for me. The functions.js file?